# What are the sizes of an intinli and an intunli?

Tags: integer

I have a specification describing values in a byte array. It says the information is stored in intinli and another one as intunli. I couldn´t find any sites describing those datatypes and their size in bytes.

EDIT: to preceise my question, this is where I found it:

[image: specification]

Answer (score 0):

intunli stands for an unsigned integer little , which is 2 bytes long.
But what is intinli ?